# Column "name" does not belong to table

Tags: c#, .net, dataset

I have data that comes back from a BLL (outside my control) as a DataSet. I know that it only takes up one row of the relevant table, so I'm accessing it like so: `_appData = myDataSet.Tables["TableName"].Rows[0]`. I then access individual data points by calling that row with the column name: `_appData["ColumnName"].ToString()`.

This works fine for most of my data, but I get a "column does not belong to table" error for a column that I know exists. Here's the error breaking in debug mode:

[image: break in debug]

As you can see the column is question is called "hadDataCompromise." Here's the column showing up when I break and dig into the DataSet -> Table -> Column:

[image]

And for good measure, I tried accessing the column in the Immediate Window, using the exact same syntax I use in my actual code, which works perfectly, returning the expected value:

[image]

Any clues why this might be happening? None of the similar questions seem to apply to my problem (most of them involve typos or extraneous quotation marks or brackets). And again, the code works fine for most columns, but randomly breaks on this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a trailing space dude.

[image]

```
private string Retrieve(string columnName)
{
    return _appData[columnName.Trim()].ToString();
}
```

The `.Trim()` function is fine but you should rather check the source your passed name is coming from.

Comment: Welp, I don't know whether to laugh or cry. I'll go add Trim() and then yell at my data guys.